# Can I put a static image in a UIButton.imageView? that is animating?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a custom `UIButton` (`MovesButton`) with an image that I don't want to change or remove. But when I set `button.imageView?.animationImages` with bunch of images and start animating it, it removes my button's initial photo I have. If I have the static photo as a background, it looks like it is on fire. I want the fire to be as a background and preferably in the same `UIButton` class.

```
private func putAnimation(button: MovesButton) {
    var images: [UIImage] = []
    if button.animation == ButtonAnimations.None {
        print("None11")
        return
    } else if button.animation == ButtonAnimations.SmallFire {
        for i in 0 ... ButtonAnimations.SmallFire.1 {
            images.append(UIImage(named: "\(ButtonAnimations.SmallFire.0)\(i)")!) //ButtonAnimations.SmallFire.0 = "smallFire"
        }
    } else if button.animation == ButtonAnimations.BigFire {
        for i in 0 ... ButtonAnimations.BigFire.1 {
            images.append(UIImage(named: "\(ButtonAnimations.BigFire.0)\(i)")!)
        }
    } else { print("weird button animations") }

    button.imageView?.animationImages = images
    button.imageView?.animationDuration = 1
    button.imageView?.startAnimating()

}
```

I don't want to use a hacky trick of putting an `imageView` or another button behind `MovesButton`

I want the same animation result as a `button.imageView.animationImages` but as the `backgroundImage`. Is this possible?

Comment: How is the button's initial photo set? What is `MovesButton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of image view animation, use *image* animation. Call UIImage `animatedImage(with:duration:)` to form an animated image. Set that as your button’s background image and you’re all set.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I basically added this
    
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: 1), for: .normal)